# Export data to excel from sql server database using Date column in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a program that will query my data in sql server and export to excel , i have 2 txtbox in my form. txtFrom_Date and txtTo_Date, 1 btnGenerateReport button. User will enter the starting date and the until date in txtbox and when click btnGenerate it will auto export the data to excel for the specified date.

below is my whole code in report form:
when i run my program and type in txtFrom_Date 2018-02-21 and txtTo_Date 2018-02-21 i got an error message "incorrect syntaxt near '2018'. but when i check my database the format is just like that. 
Please help me how to solve this thank you .

```
'NOTE before coding export excel function must add reference first in 
 project properties(microsoft excel 2012)
 'References that we need
       Imports System.Data.SqlClient
      Imports System.Data
      Imports System.IO.Directory
      Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 'Before you add this reference 
     to your project,
   ' you need to install Microsoft Office and find last version of this 
    file.
   Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

     Public Class Report


Dim dataAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
Dim dataSet As New DataSet
Dim command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
Dim datatableMain As New System.Data.DataTable()
Dim connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("SERVER=L4SMTDB01\SMTDBS02;DATABASE=SMT_IT;user=sa;pwd=qwerty;")

Private Sub ReleaseObject(ByVal o As Object)
    Try
        While (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o) > 0)
        End While
    Catch
    Finally
        o = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnGenerateReport_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGenerateReport.Click
    ' command.CommandText = String.Format("Select * from ComponentCheckerSystem where Last_Update between  " & DateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToOADate() & " and " & DateTimePicker2.Value.Date.ToOADate() & "")
    ' command.CommandText = String.Format("Select * from ComponentCheckerSystem where Last_Update >=  ''" & txtFromDate.Text & "'' and Last_Update <= ''" & txtToDate.Text & "''")
    'Assign your connection string to connection object
    command.Connection = connection
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    '' 'You can use any command sel
    command.CommandText = String.Format("Select * from ComponentCheckerSystem where Last_Update between  ''" & txtFromDate.Text & "'' and ''" & txtToDate.Text & "''")

    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command
    connection.Close()



    Dim f As FolderBrowserDialog = New FolderBrowserDialog
    Try
        If f.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            'This section help you if your language is not English.
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
            Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
            Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
            Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
            oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
            oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

            Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
            Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
            Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
            Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

            'Fill data to datatable
            connection.Open()
            dataAdapter.Fill(datatableMain)
            connection.Close()


            'Export the Columns to excel file
            For Each dc In datatableMain.Columns
                colIndex = colIndex + 1
                oSheet.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
            Next

            'Export the rows to excel file
            For Each dr In datatableMain.Rows
                rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
                colIndex = 0
                For Each dc In datatableMain.Columns
                    colIndex = colIndex + 1
                    oSheet.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
                Next
            Next

            'Set final path
            Dim fileName As String = "\Summary of Operator Scan Wrong Items" + ".xls"    'just set the file Name 
            Dim finalPath = f.SelectedPath + fileName
            txtPath.Text = finalPath
            oSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
            'Save file in final path
            oBook.SaveAs(finalPath, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, _
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, _
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)

            'Release the objects
            ReleaseObject(oSheet)
            oBook.Close(False, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
            ReleaseObject(oBook)
            oExcel.Quit()
            ReleaseObject(oExcel)
            'Some time Office application does not quit after automation: 
            'so i am calling GC.Collect method.
            GC.Collect()

            MessageBox.Show("Export done successfully!")

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End Try
End Sub



Private Sub Report_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "YYYY-MMMM-DD"
    DateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = "YYYY-MMMM-DD"

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You are using two single-quotes for the dates. so try `'" & txtFromDate.Text & "'` instead of `''" & txtFromDate.Text & "''` (for the other date too).

Comment: Thanks now it worksss...salute you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never trust what a user will put in a text box. It could be very bad for your database. Learn to use parameters. This will protect your DB and save headaches formatting you SQL Strings. Add 2 DateTimePickers to your form.

```
command.Connection = connection
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
command.CommandText = "Select * from ComponentCheckerSystem where Last_Update between @FromDate AND @ToDate;"
command.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
command.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker2.Value.Date
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion now i used parameters.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this.. thanks again. can you help me to my new questions. @Mary

Comment: why some answer doesn't have check mark to the left of the answer?

Comment: i want to modify my code to auto save in D:\work , so that i will not choose the path manually and when i save file it will auto rename to data01,data02,data03 so that i will not delete the existing file .

Comment: Please post your new question as a new question. This way other users searching for answers will be helped.

Comment: i was creating my question a while ago i'm not sure if i post it already. but when i create again it said i can post question after 90 minutes so it means i post it already. but i can't see it. @Mary

Comment: It is there. Hit your refresh button in your browser.

Comment: Yes @Mary it now shows but my English is not clear , someone commented he not understand. hope you will .

Comment: I already check your answer above ? what do you mean accept ? please help to my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49080512/how-to-auto-delete-file-in-drive-d-depends-on-selected-date-in-monthcalendar-in

Comment: please vote all my queations that you answer. So that my reputaion will increase and i can able to ask questions again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim cmdBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim changes As DataSet
    Dim sql As String
    Dim i As Int32

    Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        connetionString = "Data Source=EXCEL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Trusted_Connection=True;"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        sql = "Select * from Orders"
        Try
            connection.Open()
            adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Sql, connection)
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'NOTE:  for this code to work, there must be a PK on the Table
        Try
            cmdBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
            changes = ds.GetChanges()
            If changes IsNot Nothing Then
                adapter.Update(changes)
            End If
            MsgBox("Changes Done")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Click
        DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Orange
    End Sub
End Class
```